# What happened with my time display?

Tags: gnome, 19.10, time, clock

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and the display of time has an extra space between : separator, see images.
I notice this in gnome's top bar and in Files.

[image: Top bar]

[image: Files]

EDIT:

The spacing between hour and minute should look like this:

[image: Correct top bar]

I also tried creating a new user account to see if the problem persists with clean account.

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 20.10. But I already have the dejavu fonts installed. Apparently, the date and time is not using the right font. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved.

I installed Onlyoffice which also installed dejavu fonts as a dependency then suddenly my issue was gone. So maybe the problem was missing dejavu fonts? odd.. I did not confirm this with removing the fonts to see if issue came back.